# How to change color of text in ActionBar Spinner drop-down?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-theme

In my theme file, I have the following code to change the colors of the spinner's drop down:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomActionOverflowDropDownText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionOverflowDropDownText" parent="@android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item> <!--This does not work-->
   </style>
</resources>
```

However, the text color isn't changing.  Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to do it by overriding `getDropDownView` in the `ArrayAdapter`:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    return view;
}
```